# Java compress/decompress large files (>1gb)

Tags: java, android, file, compression

I have made an application in android that lets the user compress and decompress files and I used the package `java.util.zip`. Everything is okay. the speed, files are totally compressed and decompressed together with the directories. The only problem is that the application is not able to compress/decompress large files (greater than 1gb).

I believe the problem is the size of my `buffer`. Other codes that I've seen, the value of their buffer is 1024 or 2048 or 8192 but my value of my buffer is base on the size of the chosen file (just to make it flexible). But once the user chose a large file (with a size of >8 digits), that's were the error comes out. I searched over the net and also here in this site but I can't find an answer. my problem is similar to this:

[To Compress a big file in a ZIP with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770776/to-compress-a-big-file-in-a-zip-with-java)

Thanks for the future help! :)

EDIT:

Thanks for the comments and answers. It really helped a lot. I thought `BUFFER` in compressing/decompressing in java means the size of file so in my program, I made the buffer size flexible (buffer size = file size). Will someone please explain how buffer works so I can understand why is it okay that `BUFFER` has a fixed value. Also for me to figure it out why others people is telling that it is much better if the buffer size is 8k or else. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Please post your code - especially the part where you pick the buffer size. I suspect your buffer just ends up being too large.

Comment: There is no need to adjust the buffer size according to the file size. If anything, it would need to adjust to match to I/O layer beneath it. That is tricky and probably not portable. Just have a fixed buffer size.

Comment: Polynomial, Your right that is my case. Because of what Thilo has commented, I realized that I misunderstood the function of `buffer`. +1 to both of you. So it means that a fixed value of a buffer can compress/decompress any size of a file? so whats the purpose of different buffer sizes? 1024, 2048, 8192 and so on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you size the buffer to the size of the file, then it means that you will have OutOfMemoryError whenever the file size is too big for memory available.

Use a normal buffer size and let it do it's work - buffering the data in a streaming fashion, one chunk at a time, rather than all in one go.

For explanation, see for example the documentation of [BufferedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html):

> The class implements a buffered output stream. By setting up such an
>   output stream, an application can write bytes to the underlying output
>   stream without necessarily causing a call to the underlying system for
>   each byte written.

So using a buffer is more efficient than non-buffered writing.

And from the [write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#write%28int%29) method:

> Ordinarily this method stores bytes from the given array into this
>   stream's buffer, flushing the buffer to the underlying output stream
>   as needed. If the requested length is at least as large as this
>   stream's buffer, however, then this method will flush the buffer and
>   write the bytes directly to the underlying output stream.

Each write causes the in-memory buffer to fill up, until the buffer is full. When the buffer is full, it is flushed and cleared. If you use a very large buffer, you will cause a large amount of data to be stored in memory before flushing. If your buffer is the same size as the input file, then you are saying you need to read the whole content into memory before flushing it. Using the default buffer size is usually just fine. There will be more physical writes (flushes); you avoid exploding memory.

By allowing you to specify a specific buffer size, the API is letting you choose the right balance between memory consumption and i/o to suit your application. If you tune your application for performance, you might end up tweaking buffer size. But the default size will be reasonable for many situations.

Comment: Good buffer size would be about 8K

Comment: Yep that is my case. OutOfMemoryError. Will you also explain to me how the buffer works? Because I thought that the buffer size must be equal to the size of file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Konstantin, Thanks for the suggestion! But can you explain to me why for me to have a better understanding. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it would help to simply set a maximum size for the buffer, something like:

```
//After calculating the buffer size bufSize:
bufSize = Math.min(bufSize, MAXSIZE);
```

Comment: Why make the buffer bigger at all?

Comment: @Thilo no idea, buffer sizes above 8k usually provide very little benefit. I just assumed John wanted to use variable buffers, since that is what he is doing.